# How to sort data via drop down list

Tags: php, mysql

i am working on car dealer website where client can post different-different types of cars. Customer can categories or view the car on the basic of White plate or Yellow plate.

What my query id:
There is a category page where i am displaying all types of car by default. but i need when customer select any value from down down data will change as per selecting value. Here is the drop down code:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="b-infoBar__select-one">
                    <span class="b-infoBar__select-one-title">SORT BY</span>
                    <select name="cartype" id="cartype" class="m-select">
                        <option value="" selected="">Select Car Type</option>
                        <?php
                            $query=mysql_query("select * from cartype");
                            while($display=mysql_fetch_array($query))
                                {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $display['cartype']; ?>"><?php echo $display['cartype']; ?></option>
                        <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
```

This is my data display code:

```
<div class="row">
                       <?php
                        $query=mysql_query("select * from productdetail");
                        while($display=mysql_fetch_array($query))
                            {
                       ?>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="b-items__cell wow zoomInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                                <div class="b-items__cars-one-img">
                                    <a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $display['id']; ?>"><img class='img-responsive' src="images/product/<?php echo $display['img']; ?>" width="400" height="300" alt='chevrolet'/></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="b-items__cell-info">
                                    <div class="s-lineDownLeft b-items__cell-info-title">
                                        <a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $display['id']; ?>"><h2 class=""><?php echo $display['companyname']; ?></h2></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row m-smallPadding">
                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><?php echo $display['make']; ?></li>
                                                <li><?php echo $display['model']; ?></li>
                                                <li><?php echo $display['status']; ?></li>
                                                <li><?php echo $display['fueltype']; ?></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <h5 class="b-items__cell-info-price"><?php echo $display['price']; ?></h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                            <div class="b-items__cell-info-km">
                                                <img src="assets/icon/meter.png" />
                                                <p><?php echo $display['kilometer']; ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $display['id']; ?>" class="btn m-btn">VIEW DETAILS<span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
```

Comment: use jquery onchange then get data from ajax and load it on your page

Comment: do you have any link ??

Comment: coz drop-down values come from database...

Comment: no problem bro use jquery ajax and fetch data again

Comment: Don't use PHP's mysql_ API

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function myFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    var cartype = document.getElementById("cartype").selectedIndex;

    var queryString = "?cartype=" + cartype;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "your get data page .php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

//-->
</script>



<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="b-infoBar__select-one">
                    <span class="b-infoBar__select-one-title">SORT BY</span>
                    <select name="cartype" id="cartype" onchange="myFunction()">
                        <option value="" selected="">Select Car Type</option>
                       <!--  <?php
                            $query=mysql_query("select * from cartype");
                          /*  while($display=mysql_fetch_array($query))*/
                                {
                        ?> -->
                        <option value="VOLVO">VOLVO</option>
<!--                         <?php
                            }
                        ?> -->
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i just want to know how the drop down values will come by this code ?

Comment: @Overseas when you select any value from drop down it will pass to the your "get data page .php" written  in my ajax function and there you will get data of whichever car type you have selected from drop down .write query in that page to get data and it will display back to your main page.  
that is <div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>

Comment: you can customize the code as per your requirements i just cleared the concept of getting data using ajax.

Comment: that's what i understood you can correct me if am doing wrong so that i can improve my answer.